# Pagination on Google Analytics using Java

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I'm implementing a data extraction from Google Analytics using Java and I'm following this example: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

I managed to extract the data I need but I can't figure out how to set the `start-index` using its client. Below you can see the changed I made to the default implementation. I can set the page size but I can't find out how to set the `start-index`.

```
public GetReportsResponse getReport(String dateStart, String dateEnd) throws IOException {

        String[] metricsArr = {"ga:users", "ga:newUsers", "ga:sessions", "ga:totalEvents"};
        String[]  dimensionsArr = {"ga:eventLabel","ga:eventCategory","ga:eventAction", "ga:country", "ga:countryIsoCode", "ga:dateHourMinute"};

        // Create the DateRange object.
        DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
        dateRange.setStartDate(dateStart);
        dateRange.setEndDate(dateEnd);

        // Create the Metrics object.
        ArrayList<Metric> metrics = new ArrayList<Metric>();
        for(String item : metricsArr){
            Metric m = new Metric().setExpression(item).setAlias(item.replace("ga:", ""));
            metrics.add(m);
        }

        ArrayList<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
        for(String item : dimensionsArr){
            Dimension d = new Dimension().setName(item);
            dimensions.add(d);
        }

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
                .setViewId(this.VIEW_ID)
                .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
                .setMetrics(metrics)
                .setDimensions(dimensions)
                .setFiltersExpression("ga:eventCategory=@NOTICE,ga:eventCategory==Document,ga:eventCategory==Document reader")
                .setPageSize(10000);

        ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
        requests.add(request);

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest().setReportRequests(requests);

        // Call the batchGet method.
        GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

        // Return the response.
        return response;
    }
```

How can I achieve that so I can navigate through all pages and extract all items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reporting API V4 uses page tokens. The reply from the reporting API will return the next page's token, see [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#report). Using that you can make the exact same call but updating the [pageToken](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportrequest) in the request with the nextpagetoken from the previous reply. Note that the first call you make the reporting API will not have a page token attached to the request and the last page will not have the nextpagetoken set.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. When debugging I saw just an integer number that made not much sense for me, but that's how it's done.